# About the "Spindown problem"

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, relativity, gravitational-waves

I am studying General Relativity, following the lessons too, and some days ago the professor mentioned, in a very "fancy and quick" way a thing called "the spindown problems".

For what I understood, it has to do with gravitational waves, yet I have asked to my colleagues and I tried to teach on the web for explanation and **nothing**.

I cannot find a suitable, good and clear explanation of what it is meant by spindown problems.

Papers I have found are either very advanced or very elementary (or they don't explain it at all).

So I am asking to you: is there someone here willing to give me a quite complete detailed explanation of this topic?

I also accepts notes or references, provided they are clear and understandable for a student (I know about tensors, Einstein equations, their solutions, linearization, in short: I know maths and physics at a quite good level).

Thank you!

Comment: When two black holes merge the original *dumbbell* geometry has to relax into an axially symmetric Kerr geometry i.e. the quadrupolar and higher moments of the geometry have to be radiated away as gravitational waves. This is the spindown. It's notoriously hard to compute numerically.